# Call curl using cmd?

Tags: curl, cmd

I have the following curl command that I want to convert to .bat file to calling using cmd.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.telerivet.com/v1/projects/PJ331378e28e30b89f/messages/send \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic TFFWcHR6SkxMS0x2a1JwbDBKelBTMExnVHdQbzdybFM6' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 6fde3920-a30d-4daa-9535-ac6373d492f8' \
  -d '{
    "content": "kjdjefk",
    "to_number": "+6586524931"

}'
```

But get the following error.

[image]

Comment: In cmd, `^` is the escape character.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
curl -X POST ^
  https://api.telerivet.com/v1/projects/PJ331378e28e30b89f/messages/send ^
  -H 'Authorization: Basic TFFWcHR6SkxMS0x2a1JwbDBKelBTMExnVHdQbzdybFM6' ^
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' ^
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' ^
  -H 'Postman-Token: 6fde3920-a30d-4daa-9535-ac6373d492f8' ^
  -d '{^
    "content": "kjdjefk",^
    "to_number": "+6586524931"^
}'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: @RobertColumbia in this case, isn't it super obvious? the ^ is a general `escape character` in .bat, and in this case, it escapes the newlines. was there ever any doubt as to what the ^ did in this snippet?

Comment: @hanshenrik It may be obvious to you, but not necessarily to others. It is *never bad* to explain why your answer is right.